# static spherically symmetric gravitational field

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, orbital-motion

Say a star orbits in a static, spherically symmetric gravitational field. What does this mean mathematically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of static is that it doesn't change in time. The meaning of spherically symmetric is that it is the same in all directions, if you rotate the coordinate axis the gravitational field will be the same.